# input inside label firefox error without block

Tags: html, firefox, radio-button

Any idea why firefox acts so weird with this code? 
It works perfect in IE & Chrome.

```
<LEGEND>Basistaal </LEGEND>
<LABEL class=alg_kantoor_taal for=alg_kantoor_taal>
<INPUT id=alg_kantoor_taal value=NL type=radio name=alg_kantoor_taal .>
NL
</LABEL>

<LABEL class=alg_kantoor_taal for=alg_kantoor_taal>
<INPUT id=alg_kantoor_taal value=FR type=radio name=alg_kantoor_taal .>FR</LABEL>
```

I have seen another question where firefox behaved strange because there was a block element inside the label. That is not the case here. I would have like to keep this structure since my css is based up this html... Guess i will have to change it to get it working in FF?

edit-> fiddle here :http://jsfiddle.net/ZXSKH/59/ you can see in firefox the radiobuttons just don't work as they should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll save you the trouble and fix the HTML for you:

```
<LEGEND>Basistaal</LEGEND>
<INPUT id="alg_kantoor_taal-nl" value="NL" type="radio" name="alg_kantoor_taal" />
<LABEL class="alg_kantoor_taal" for="alg_kantoor_taal">NL</LABEL>

<INPUT id="alg_kantoor_taal-fr" value="FR" type="radio" name="alg_kantoor_taal" />
<LABEL class="alg_kantoor_taal" for="alg_kantoor_taal">FR</LABEL>
```

An element are built up with a opening and closing tag, or a single tag.

Double tag: `<tagname>content</tagname>`

Single tag: `<tagname />`

Also, an attribute should be surrounded with quotes: `<tagname attribute="value" />`

Please note that an element id should be **unique at all times**. You can't have 2 elements with the same id.

In fact, this should fix most of your problems. But please, for the love of god, learn how to use HTML **properly** first.

Comment: Removing the id solved the problem. Creating 2 radiobuttons in pure html it's easy to follow the perfect syntax. When you build a form with more then 75 input elements dynamically it's not always easy to follow the rules perfectly. Thanks for your input.

Comment: My apologies for my rudeness, it was uncalled for. So after all, the problem were the id's? Well, glad to help! Again, my apologies.

Answer (score 1):

All elements on a page should have a unique `id`. Both of the lables reference the second input. You should give each `input` a unique `id` and change the `for` attribute of the `label` to reference the new id. Or you could remove the `id` and `for` attributes and it would work how you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `input` tags out of the labels.

```
<LEGEND>Basistaal</LEGEND>
<INPUT id="alg_kantoor_taal1" value="NL" type="radio" name="alg_kantoor_taal" />
<LABEL class="alg_kantoor_taal" for="alg_kantoor_taal1">NL</LABEL>

<INPUT id="alg_kantoor_taal2" value="FR" type="radio" name="alg_kantoor_taal" />
<LABEL class="alg_kantoor_taal" for="alg_kantoor_taal2">FR</LABEL>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXSKH/61/